# ImagePicker Plugin in ionic cordova

Tags: cordova

I am new in ionic framework can you help me for image-picker in ionic, I have created a simple image sharing app in ionic in which i have to pick images from gallery and camera both just like whats app profile picture change i want exactly this type of picker in ionic can someone help me for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Those both options are a part of Cardova Camera plugin.

1. Add a plugin to your project: `ionic plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera`. Read more [here](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/cordova-camera/)
2. Select your `sourceType` depending on your needs. Possible values are `Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA` or `Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY`

Your code should be like this one:

```
// Select your type as following:
// var sourceType = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
// var sourceType = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
// 
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(url){
            // the url contains selected image or a camera result

          }, function() {
              // handle error
          },
          {  //camera options
              quality: 50,
              destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
              sourceType: sourceType
          });
```

I used [ionisActionSheet](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicActionSheet/) to allow user select preferred option.